# Could alien nanobots re-engineer humans using xeno nucleic acids?

Tags: science-based, xenobiology

Is it possible for alien nanobots to give humans new abilities (kinda like superpowers such as enhanced strength, carapace against gunfire, etc.) by altering their DNA using XNA without killing the host? If this is not possible, what kind of alternative ways would nanobots do to physically transform humans?

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic." Note that your question does not place any restriction on the technology. So if the technology level you imagine is not sufficient for what you like, then you just imagine a higher level and it will solve it. The answer will always be "Yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it would be like viruses.**

Some viruses, called retroviruses, do very similar things. They have RNA, which while not alien is different from DNA, and use an enzyme called reverse transcriptase to convert RNA to DNA and program the cells to make more copies. These do things like cause AIDs, to give a famous example.

Your special alien virus would have an enzyme like alien transcriptase which would insert itself into the DNA of humans, and force them to produce new improved proteins and compounds to make your alien human hybrid better, and produce more XNA to infect new cells.

**How to do super strength.**

There's three things you can do. Three levels. The first level is hysterical strength. This is a very rapid modification where you tweak nervous connections to make every muscle fibre pulse at once, and lower pain. This would rapidly damage the human, but allow them to display short bursts of strength useful to their alien overlords.

The second level is to alter the proportion of slow and fast twitch muscles. Humans have a high proportion of slow twitch muscles, which make us better at high endurance tasks and high precision tasks. Chimps have more high twitch muscles, which make them good at ripping people's arms off. They are known to be much stronger than humans. They could make this modification, to double or triple human strength, at the cost of endurance and precision.

The third level is to make radically more powerful alien muscles. This would be difficult and complex, but would have the potential to make them have muscles as powerful as pneumatic pistols, able to generate vast amounts of force.

Making bulletproof skin requires the third level of modification. It would be an expensive and difficult modification requiring radically changing human skin to weave in kevlar fibres or carbon nanotubes or such.

Answer (score 2):

**Growing an internal bullet proof vest would also require a harsh diet**

Resistence against gunfire can be established when the XNA would instruct the cell to form some kind of very stiff, protective *and* permeable tissue (carapace) around the body, each cell closely connected to similar neighbour cells. Kind of a second skin. Given unlimited technological abilty, such a building plan could very well be constructed in foreign DNA (or XNA)

But any DNA-type of action can only contain a *plan*, it will not build and chain the  molecules itself, the cell will do that, using resources the bloodstream provides, through the design ("mould") formed by DNA/XNA. Certain base components should be consumed, be part of the food. So an additional "XNA-therapy" would be helpful, to let the person appreciate and *endure* food that contains the basic materials for a bullet-proof type of skin. It could involve having to eat arsenic, polymeric fluids, or certain metals.. just drinking milk (calcium) won't do against bullets.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you manage to make a protein that builds carbon nanotubes, and arranges them into fibers, you could probably build a bulletproof skin with only carbon (which is largely present in the human diet)

Comment: Cells don't create carbon nanotubes, it's an industrial process.. so if your solution would work, the person would need to eat food with (a lot of) that basic resource (nanotubes) in it !

Comment: Normal cells don't, but maybe alien-reengineered cells could. Though this transformation might just need too much energy :/

Comment: Ok with unknown alien technology involved, you could always confirm *any* thinkable *possibility*, so the answer here will always be "yes". The question was open, yes or no. I think no, the body needs the resources to actually build the XNA-plan. XNA alone will not do the job,  I found this..  *"Carbon nanotubes can be synthesized using different methods. Amongst the most common arc discharge [1-5], laser ablation [6], chemical vapor deposition (CVD) from hydrocarbons [7-11] and high pressure conversion of carbon monoxide (HiPco)"* https://sites.google.com/site/cntcomposites/production-methods